# how to handle MySQL NULL in C++ using mysql.h?

Tags: c++, mysql, null

I'm trying to check for certain field values in an `if`.  Most of these values are `NULL` in MySQL.

It seems to be screwing everything up.

I do

```
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=NULL){
    if(row[1] != "-1"){
        rows.push_back(row[0]);
    }
}
```

The field for `row[1]` is an `INT` `LENGTH` `1` equal to `1`, `-1`, or `NULL`.  Most are `NULL`, but a few are `-1`.  I *think* that `mysql.h` outputs all values as `char*` (at least that's the only way I've been able to get it to work so far).

Anyways, strangely, `rows` gets filled, but it's filled with "nothing".  I'm not even sure if it's an empty string or what.

Please help.

Many thanks in advance!

---

I put dashes in front and behind the `std::cout` of `rows[i]` in a `for` loop.  It outputs a ton of `--`s.

If I `std::cout` the raw `row[0]`, it outputs fine.

---

For us2012:

```
std::vector< char* > rows;

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=NULL){
    std::cout << "-" << row[0] << "-" << std::endl;
    if(row[1] != "-1"){
        rows.push_back(row[0]);
    }
}

std::cout << "Valids:" << std::endl;
for(int i = 0; i < rows.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "id: -" << rows[i] << "-" << std::endl;
}
```

---

When I use this if

```
if(row[1] && row[1] != "-1")
```

The `if` works in reverse.

Note: I incremented an `int` in the `while`, `cout`ed that and `rows` and `invalidRows`.  The counter gives `389`, `rows.size()` `2`, and `invalidRows.size()` `387`.

I'm going to see if I can `cout` `row[0]` *after* I do the `if`...

---

`cout`ing `row[0]` after the `if` outputs the correct data.

---

`if(row[1] != "-1")` gives `...forbids comparison between pointer and integer...`

---

**Why `mysql.h`:**

CentOS.  I find hardly anything for it, and nothing my host supports.

---

`if(row[1] && std::string(row[1]).compare("-1") != 0)` put everything into `invalidRows`

Without `row[`] &&`gave`what(): basic_string::_S_construct NULL not valid Aborted`

---

**Answer**

It was `if(row[1] && std::string(row[1]).compare("-1") == 0)` all along!  My logic got screwed up in all of the C++ crash coursing.

And using `std::vector< std::string >` allows `row[x]` to be `push`ed`_back`.

Comment: `I'm not even sure if it's an empty string`... It would be really nice if you found that out. Do some debugging and tell us what actually is in `rows`. By the way, the info about data format is all in the mysql api doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-fetch-row.html , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-data-structures.html , so there is no need to guess what types the returned values have...

Comment: For starters, check what `rows.size()` is after the `while` loop returns. Does this match with the number of results you are expecting from your query? Also have a look at the example in the first link I gave you. Try it on your query.

Comment: Okay, the bit about `row[0]` printing fine is valuable. In that case, let's see the code that you use to print `rows[i]`, and while you're at it, include the line where you declare and define `rows`.

Comment: Please attach the entire *output* of your program.

Comment: NO! `if(row[1] && row[1] != "-1")` is WRONG WRONG WRONG!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: The API you are using is a C API. There's nothing inherently wrong about that, but it means that you have to deal with a lot of stuff that seems unneccessary because 
 C++ has better tools available for this. If possible, you should therefore use a C++ wrapper like MySQL++ : http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/ (all credits for this suggestion go to @Non-Stop Time Travel in the comments below)

---

In your original code, you're not comparing strings, you're comparing addresses. Your condition compares the memory address stored in `row[1]` with the memory address of the constant string literal `"-1"`. What you actually want (if you stick to `char *`) is `strcmp` : [C++ Compare char array with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330550/c-compare-char-array-with-string)

You're also pushing back pointers to `row[0]` which is temporary, it is reassigned with every iteration of the while loop! You have to make a copy of these and store the pointers to the copies.

This is a very quick idea of how you could approach this. Not really good C++, though (in fact, if it were not for the vector and the cout, it may as well be C. See above for the reasons.):

```
#include <string.h>

std::vector<char*> rows;
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=NULL){
    if(strcmp(row[1],"-1") != 0){
        char * store = new char[strlen(row[0])+1];
        strncpy(store ,row[0] ,strlen(row[0])+1);
        rows.push_back(store);
    }
}
std::cout << "Valids:" << std::endl;
for(int i = 0; i < rows.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "id: -" << rows[i] << "-" << std::endl;
}

//clean up
for(int i = 0; i < rows.size(); ++i)
{
    delete [] rows[i];
}
```

---

In general, when you deal with strings in C++ I would recommend using `std::string` and `std::string::compare` instead<strike>, but this is problematic here - if your mysql rows hold binary data, you don't have guaranteed null-terminated strings anymore (see the spec for MYSQL_ROW here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-data-structures.html ).</strike> As pointed out by *Non-Stop Time Travel* in the comments below, `std::string` supports internal `\0`s, the code example below however doesn't work with them.

```
#include <string>

//this particular code works only if row[0] and row[1] are nullterminated

std::vector<std::string> rows;
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=NULL){
    if(std::string(row[1]).compare("-1") != 0){
        rows.push_back(std::string(row[0]));
    }
}
std::cout << "Valids:" << std::endl;
for(int i = 0; i < rows.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "id: -" << rows[i] << "-" << std::endl;
}

//cleaning up the vector of strings is not necessary! yay!
```

)

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy I can't really see where I'm producing a segfault here, but I'm really tired so I may be missing something. Maybe your program cleans up the pointers later? Leave out my `clean up` section and try again.

Comment: @JoeCodeGuy There is a huge amount of basics to cover, I'm afraid :). Oh, before I forget: This (a project which interfaces with mysql) is not a good project to start learning C++ with. The mysql API is essentially a C API.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy added an approach using `std::string`.

Comment: `std::string` supports strings with NULLs in them, precisely as much as your original `char*` do. `std::string` is **absolutely** the way to go. Better yet, use a C++ MySQL library in the first place (such as MySQL++).

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel Thanks for the clarification, I'll edit that in my post, however my use of the constructor `std::string(const char *)` in my code sample *does* require a null-terminated string.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel I think you should turn your suggestion of MySQL++ into an answer.

Comment: @us2012: CBA. Go for it :)

Comment: Why do you have to `clean up` `rows`?  Does it stick around after the code has finished?  Thanks for getting me over this hump!

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy That's too much to explain in an answer to this question. You should buy a good book about C++ where these things are explained. Until then - as stated above, the solution with `std::string` does not require manual cleanup.