# strcmp not comparing

Tags: c, linked-list, strcmp

I need some assistance with the strcmp function. I am trying to compare a const char word with a char array.But for whatever reason, strcmp is not comparing the two types.Here is what I have:

```
typedef struct Node {    
    char word[LENGTH+1];  
    struct Node *Next;    
}
Node;


for (NodePointer=hashtable->table[hashval];NodePointer !=NULL;NodePointer=NodePointer->Next)
    {
        i=0;
        i=strcmp(word,NodePointer->word); 

        if (i==0) 
          return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

does anyone have any idea on what maybe the problem? Am I suppose to null terminate each beforehand?

Comment: `strcmp` relies on a terminating null char to signal the end of a string, so if one of your strings doesn't end with a null char, you'll certainly have a problem.

Comment: We'll probably need more than this, but yes you should nul terminate anything you pass to strcmp.

Comment: Well, I guarantee `strcmp` works on *valid* inputs, so..

Comment: Ok, and this will totally come across as a dumb question, but how would I null terminate an array within a structure?

Comment: Add the line where `word` is assigned

Comment: I guess following link might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330550/c-compare-char-array-with-string

Comment: @uba I just added the structure where I create word array.

Comment: If you know the length of your strings, but they're not null terminated, use memcmp instead. But make sure that the size you give it is the *minimum* of both lengths.

Comment: @user2014904 How are you **assigning** the values? Give an example of assigning (are you reading it from stdin?) `word` or `Node->word`

Comment: I am assigning it like this:

Comment: I am strcpying  Node->word from a buffer array. buffer is read from a file, and I'm using fscanf as the tool to read the data from the file into the buffer array...
strcpy(node-word,buffer)

Comment: Please give us a minimal, **compilable** testcase so we can diagnose your problem. Minimal means "Using only the bare essentials required to reproduce your problem". Compilable means "Using enough code for us to compile and reproduce the problem on our own systems **without filling in blanks, guessing or fixing syntax errors**. Also, if there are any warnings issued by the compiler, please provide them.

Comment: I figured it out guys...thank you anyways!

Comment: Remove the i=0 line, the effect of that are forgotten anyway in the next line.

Comment: [What is a null-terminated string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2037209/995714)

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure `word` is terminated by `'\0'`.
2. you can considering using [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/)

   strncmp(word, NodePointer->word, LENGTH)