# I am having some trouble with if function with char

Tags: c++

Here, When I input CO2, it is processing the 'else' statement and if I input anything else it is still the same

I tried changing 'co2' to "co2" but then it  doesn't even work

```
int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs)
{
    char symb[5];

    cout << "Enter Symbol: ";
    cin >> symb[5];

    if (symb[5] == 'co2')
    {
        cout << "This is Carbon-Dioxide" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char symb[5]` means an array of 5 `char`. Everywhere else, `symb[5]` means "the character at index 5". Index 5 means the sixth character (indices are 0 based).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare char array with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330550/c-compare-char-array-with-string).

Comment: Another thing, `'co2'` is not a valid string literal in C++, as single quotes are reserved for individual characters, not strings. Also worth noting, you should never be assigning nor referencing the value of `char[5]` since the permissible range of values is 0 through 4. `char[5]` is actually outside of the bounds of your array and the code as-is will lead to what we call "undefined" behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is written all wrong.

The statement `char symb[5];` declares a fixed sized array that can hold 5 `char` elements max.  But when you do `cin >> symb[5];`, you are not reading *up to* 5 `char`s into the array, you are reading *a single* `char` into the **6th** slot of the array, corrupting surrounding memory.

Also, `symb[5] == 'co2'` is not the right way to compare the contents of the array.  You are comparing the **6th** (invalid) `char` against a single multi-byte character, you are not comparing the whole content of the array against a multi-character string.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char symb[5];

    cout << "Enter Symbol: ";
    cin.get(symb, 5);

    if (strcmp(symb, "co2") == 0)
    {
        cout << "This is Carbon-Dioxide" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, using a `std::string` instead of a `char[]` is better:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string symb;

    cout << "Enter Symbol: ";
    cin >> symb;

    if (symb == "co2")
    {
        cout << "This is Carbon-Dioxide" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And if you really want to have fun you can use a `std::map` to map the symbol to the description. This lets you write code that looks like `cout << symbols[symb];`

Comment: Thanks for your help... I m a beginner at c++ and I was having some problem with this code, you really did me a favor...